# PDO Exception not being caught

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to learn about using the PDO method to access mysql databases.  In the following code sample I have created a test program which works fine when there is no exception.  To generate an exception I added a mandatory third field to the table so that the execute statement would fail.  What I am hoping to do is test the 'catch' branch, but after trying several different thing I always get an 'uncaught exception error' from that line, eg.:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'Tst_integer' doesn't have a default value' in /var/www/ccc/ccc/cccccy/zztest.php:46

Line 46 corresponds to the execute statement.

Why is the exception not triggered?

---

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

class pdo_connect {
   var $pdo_con;
   var $message;

   function __construct(){
      $cur_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

      $BDconfig = array(
         'host'   => 'localhost',
         'user'   => 'p2p_user',
         'pass'    => 'keith1',
         'dbname' => 'p2p_notes_data'
      );

      $db_host = $BDconfig['host'];
      $db_user = $BDconfig['user'];
      $db_pass = $BDconfig['pass'];
      $db_name = $BDconfig['dbname'];
      $dsn = 'mysql:dbname='. $db_name . ';' . 'host=' . $db_host;

      // mysql connect information, pass 
      try{
         $this->pdo_con = new PDO ($dsn, $db_user, $db_pass);
         $this->pdo_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
         //$this->pdo_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
      } catch (\PDOException $e) {
         echo '$cur_date' . " " . 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
         die();
      }
   }

   function __destruct(){
      $this->pdo_con = null;
   }
}
   $dbh = new pdo_connect;
   //$dbh->pdo_con->beginTransaction();
   $field1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   $field2 = 'mytst';
   $sth = $dbh->pdo_con->prepare("INSERT INTO test_table (Tst_Date,Tst_String) VALUES (:field1,:field2);");
   try {
      $sth->execute(array(":field1" => $field1, ":field2" => $field2));
   } catch (PDOExeption $e) {
      //$dbh->pdo_con->rollBack();
      echo $e->getMessage();
      echo 'ttttt', PHP_EOL;
   }
   //$dbh->pdo_con->commit();

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo

```
PDOExeption 
     ^-- missed c
```